# whats wrong with my makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to run the make as below. It is throwing an error saying

Makefile:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

Where am I going wrong?

```
listtest: listtest.o my402list.o
        gcc -o listtest -g listtest.o my402list.o

listtest.o: listtest.c my402list.h
        gcc -g -c -Wall listtest.c

my402list.o: my402list.c my402list.h
        gcc -g -c -Wall my402list.c

clean:
        rm -f *.o listtest
```

EDIT:
Environment variable dump is as below

```
SSH_AGENT_PID=1419
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-Onhywf/gpg:0:1
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=e8bbd04010b1d6a944276b9351501289-1370438922.688778-1401523550
WINDOWID=62916515
OLDPWD=/home/k
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-Onhywf
GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module
USER=k
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-Onhywf/ssh
SESSION_MANAGER=local/k-cm:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1345,unix/k-cm:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1345
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
PATH=/home/k/Downloads/android-ndk-r8e:/home/k/Downloads/android-ndk-r8e:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/k/Dev/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/k/Dev/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
PWD=/home/k/Desktop/zzz
LANG=en_IN
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
SPEECHD_PORT=7560
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/k
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME=k
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-MTjWfcMEFq,guid=bb158504e03c6f5867f8c86c0000001f
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY=/home/k/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I tried running make with --no-builtin-rules, same error

Directory Listing

```
total 44
drwxrwxr-x 2 k k 4096 Jun  8 23:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 k k 4096 Jun  8 21:25 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 k k  685 Jun  4 22:08 cs402.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 k k 5484 Jun  8 21:22 listtest.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 k k  235 Jun  8 23:00 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 k k  235 Jun  8 22:46 Makefile~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 k k 8197 Jun  8 21:21 my402list.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 k k 2001 Jun  4 22:08 my402list.h
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the makefile you're using?  It looks fine.

Comment: of course. also if i run the commands separately it works fine

Comment: I don't know about 'of course'.  I copied & pasted this makefile and it works fine here.  What does `make -d` say?

Comment: GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Makefile:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

Comment: "Multiple target patterns" - what files are your directory?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Makefile, which means that the problem is somewhere else. You need to provide more information in your question, starting with a dump of all your environment variables via the `env` utility, and a complete directory listing with `ls -la`.  Also, show your `make`'s internal database with `make -p`.

Comment: Also, run `make` with the `-d` option to show a debug trace. Also try running make with `--no-builtin-rules`. You're not depending on any anyway; if it works then that confirms some interaction with the builtin rules.

Comment: Note: Other postings describe an issue with "the : in the path ".

Comment: I see Carl Norum already suggested `make -d` before I had. There may be a clue in the debug output.

Comment: Since the error occurs in line#1, this *could* be caused by a BOM being present in the Makefile. Please hexdump it and inspect the first line.

Comment: @wildplasser, Like Kaz below, I copied the OP's makefile and replaced the stack-overflow-inserted spaces with tabs, and I get the same 235 byte file size as the OP.  That would seem to indicate there's no BOM at play here.

Comment: you are right, the same happens here, and the resulting Makefile appears to work. Probably an installation/envirironment, then. Having higher (utf8) characters in the filenames could also cause the parser to see the first word as multiple tokens (while maintaining the filesize)

Comment: can you post the md5checksum of your file?

Comment: FWIW: Appears to be a 7 year old make program.  Maybe its only the (c)

Comment: 3.81 is pretty common; it's the last GPL2 version of GNU make, IIRC, so GPLv3 averse organizations keep it around.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly, that error comes from having SPACES instead of TABS before the action lines in the makefile.

Action lines MUST begin with a TAB character.

Comment: Wouldn't that say "missing separator"?

Comment: I have checked that. It is TAB, not spaces

Comment: Can you upload the Makefile somewhere, and paste link here?

Comment: When I cut and paste the Makefile and edit spaces to tabs, I get a file of length 235, like in OP's directory listing. So there is nothing hidden going on like colons that are backspaced over.

Comment: If I paste the makefile verbatim to my computer create some dummy files and make sure that I **REALLY** only have tabs at the right places it just works fine.

So I can just confirm what the others alreay said: has to be something else (either not using TABs or too many of them or something really weird in your environment.)

And as Ziffusion pointed out: Upload the Makefile somewhere so that everyone can get it like it is stored on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The "multiple target patterns" error can be reproduced with the following Makefile:

```
a: b c: d
        command
```

The `b` and `c` are the multiple target patterns. It might happen because a prerequisite contains a colon.

Perhaps you have multiple makefiles in your directory. Make sure you are running the one you are editing, using  `make -f <filename>`.

Be sure you're not making the mistake of running `make` in another terminal window where the current working directory (or even the host!) are different.

If none of these suggestions work, try downloading some small freeware program, and building it.  If that doesn't work, it suggests that you have an installation of make that is björked somehow.

There is always the possibility of bad RAM in your motherboard. If a page of the `gmake` executable is corrupt and cached, the program will misbehave each time you run it, for as long as the bad page isn't evacuated from the cache.  Try rebooting the machine. If the problem goes away, you have a hardware issue.